# How to remotely access by name a device which is only accessible locally

Tags: iptables

I have several switches with the same factory-set static address, each connected to a server with two interfaces, one server to each switch. The server's primary interface is to the local house network and it's secondary interface is to a subnet which includes the switch's address. I would like to be able to assign a name to each switch, have the name resolve to a house network address on the associated server, and configure each server to transparently forward traffic sent to that address to the switch and traffic from the switch back to the origin house network address. It seems likely that iptables NAT should be able to do that. So I have the following rules in iptables.

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -p all -s switch -j SNAT --to house
-A PREROUTING  -p all -d house  -j DNAT --to switch
```

where "switch" is the switch's static address and "house" is the house net address I've assigned to the switch. (Both are entered numerically.) Of course, since I'm writing here, this doesn't work.

Before enabling iptables, I can ping the "house" address from the server and from other devices on the house network and I can ping the "switch" address from the server. Running nmap against the switch's static address from the server, I see the proper switch ports open, running nmap against the "switch" address from another device on the house network, I see the ports which are open on the server. After enabling iptables, ping still responds though I'm not sure which device is responding. nmap to the "switch" address from the server still shows the server's ports, not the switch's. nmap from another device reports that all ports are filtered.

I'm not changing the switch's static address for reliability. I want things to continue working if the switch is reset for any reason.

All I really need to work is ping and ports 80 and 443. There must be a better solution.

Comment: Shouldn't the first rule be a `SNAT` in `POSTROUTING` rather?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that mistake. But after fixing it, things still don't work. (1) server can ping switch by its house address, others cannot. (2) server nmap to switch's house address reports server's ports, from others nmap reports all ports filtered.

Comment: and all primary interfaces are assigned the 'house' addresses as well as their 'server' IP addresses?

Comment: Yes. eth1 has the server's normal house net address, eth1:sw has the "switch" house net address. Both are on the same subnet with the same netmask.

Comment: did you use `-p all` for the rules? try without that. I mean, those rule *should* work, but that `-p all` looks fishy to me :)

Comment: According to the man page for iptables, -p indicates the protocol(s) to be forwarded. Choices are 'tcp, udp, udplite, icmp, icmpv6, esp, ah,  sctp,  mh  or  the  special  keyword  "all"'. I suppose I could choose just one but I'd like the switch to respond to ping as well as HTTP. Omitting -p is supposed to be equivalent to "all". Still, I'll try omitting it.

Comment: Omitting -p had no effect on the result. tcpdump shows that pings from another machine are reaching the server but are not being forwarded to the switch.

Comment: mmm. You do have forwarding enabled on the servers? `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (the default is "0")

Comment: Yes, forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Perhaps it is that the switches are unhappy with martians, and you'll need to masquerade out on the switch interfaces to "fool" them?

Comment: Since tcpdump shows that the traffic is not being sent to the switch, it doesn't seem that the switch is responsible for this issue.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't waiting long enough to see the traffic going to the switch. In fact it is being forwarded! It's the replies that are the problem. The switch default gateway is 0.0.0.0. If I change it to the address of the server on that interface -- not the "house" or "switch" address -- I see replies. So now I have a different problem: how to get the switch to reply without changing its default gateway (since I want this to work "out of the box"). But this issue is likely resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up as a longish comment chain :)

My last suggestion would thus be to add a rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $IFSW -j MASQUERADE
```

where `$IFSW` is the switch interface, to each server.

With that, the switches will receive the packets as sourced from their servers, and thus respond appropriately, and the servers would handle the mappings back to original addresses for the response packets.